# How can I convert a single digit day in R while importing csv using read_csv() of tidyverse?

Tags: r, date, format, tidyverse, tibble

I have 33 csv files that have dates such as 1/01/2020...31/01/2020. I have to import the files using tidyverse library's readr packages `read_csv()` and assign them in a tibble. So my code looks like this:

```
main_df <- read_csv("./data/202001.csv",
                    skip = 7,
                    col_types = cols(
                      Date = col_date(format = "%d/%m/%Y")
                    )
                 )
```

**Date** is the column name here. When I try to run this code I gives an NA value in the tibble because in the "%d" in format always recognizes 2 digit dates which is why dates like "1/01/2020" is generating "NA". How can I overcome this issue? TIA.

Comment: `"%d" in format always recognizes 2 digit dates` is not true. `as.Date(c('1/01/2020', '31/01/2020'), '%d/%m/%Y')` works. There should be some other issue in your data.

Comment: I have written a LibreOffice file with one column, 7 rows with garbage, then a header `"Date"` and 4 consecutive dates ranging from `"1/01/2020"` to `"4/01/2020"`. Saved it as csv and ran your code. It worked at the first try so there must be something else with your data, like @RonakShah said.

Answer (score 0):

Use `as.POSIXct`:

```
main_df <- read_csv("./data/202001.csv", skip = 7)
main_df['Date'] = as.POSIXct(main_df$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
main_df
```

Or if the above does't work, try `stringr` library with the `str_pad` function.

Also use `as.POSIXct`:

```
library(stringr)
main_df <- read_csv("./data/202001.csv", skip = 7)
main_df['Date'] = as.POSIXct(str_pad(main_df$Date, 10, pad = "0"), format="%d/%m/%Y")
main_df
```